# AngularJS Post not working

Tags: angularjs, post, angularjs-http

This is a function that gets executed after submitting a form which then submits data to an api, all of this is being done in angular 1.5 using the $http service

I have used postman to test this methods(GET,DELETE,POST) and others and they all work fine. In my app though POST for some reason seems note to work even though in postman i follow the same structure.

the error i get is that name is a requirement which i belie is the API ensuring information is entered.

I just cant seem to understand why this works fine in post man but not within my angular application. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 function createDocument(newMovie){


            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url:{{some url}},
                headers: 
                      { 
                        "Authorization": Authorization,
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                      },
                body: { 
                        "name": newMovie.name, 
                        "description": newMovie.description, 
                        "imgs":[
                           {
                             "url": newMovie.imgs
                           }
                        ]
                      }
             }  


            $http(req)
                .success(function(response){
                    console.log('success', response);
                })
                .error(function(response){
                    console.log('error', response);
                })
                ;
        }
```

Comment: The `.success` method is [deprecated and removed from V1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 1):

It should be data, not body.

```
data: { 
                        "name": newMovie.name, 
                        "description": newMovie.description, 
                        "imgs":[
                           {
                             "url": newMovie.imgs
                           }
                        ]
                      }
```

Comment: is it just something to do with angularJS or the $http service?

Comment: Yes, actually for it with the object with name data.

Comment: whatever data you pass, its name should be data.